# two names for the same struct in C

Tags: c, struct, names

I want to hide the nature of a public struct for an API inside my .h/.c couple, so I declare only the typedef in the .h and I complete the declaration in the .c like this:

### foo.h

```
typedef struct filters_s filters_t;

/* some public functions declaration using filters_t */
(...)
```

### foo.c

```
typedef struct filters_s filter_node_t;

struct filters_s
{
  filter_node_t *children[96];

  (...)
}
```

As you can see, filters_s is in fact the root node of a tree so internally, I'm using filter_node_t but externally, I don't want to expose the "tree" nature of the struct.
So, my "problem" is that ideally I'd like to have also another name for the struct like filter_node_s, but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Why do you want another name? What's wrong with using the typedef?

Comment: yes, it compiles but i just don't like the idea to use a struct named "filters_s" internally and to be forced to used the typedef

Comment: you can create as many tyepdef as you want

Comment: @Omkant: yes I know but if I want to use directly the struct without typedef, I'm stucked with "filters_s" and it hurts my feelings :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide the implementation of the structure then you need a opaque pointer to the structure. There you would pass this pointer to a function that will get or modify the data of the structure.

The declaration will be in the *.h header file. And the definition will be in the *.c file.

Something like this in the *.h (header file):

```
typedef struct tag_device device_t;
```

Then in the *.c (implementation file):

```
struct tag_device {
size_t id;
char *name;
};

void set_data(device_t *dev, size_t id, char *name)
{
dev->id = id;
dev->name = strdup(*name);
}
```

Then in your *.c (driver file)

```
device_t *device = malloc(sizeof *device)

set_data(device, 1, "device02345");
```

I have just typed this in, so it might not be perfect as I haven't checked for errors. Always remember to free memory after you finish with it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I already do that. I admit my question is not really clear and I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't think you can use sizeof() on an opaque/incomplete type, since the size of the struct is not known to the caller. If dynamic memory is an option, there is really no point in leaving the allocation to the caller anyhow. Instead, you should call malloc from inside a `init_device` function ("constructor"). Good answer, apart from that.

Comment: @Lundin. You are correct about the struct sizeof. I think it would just allocate 8 bytes for the pointer size. Which would result in a UB when you try and use it. I should have typed it in my emacs and compiled before posting my answer. The init_device would be more complete answer.